# Django model creation with multithreading

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-models

My Django app requires a background thread which executes every 60 seconds and reads entries from a model called "rawdata" then runs some calculations based on the data and generates a new record in another model called "results".

After doing some research I realize this can be done with celery however I feel a full async task framework is a bit of overkill for what I need.  I am new to Django and am trying to determine if my implementation below is safe.

My app launches the background process using the "ready" hook of Django like this:

```
class Myapp(AppConfig):
    name = 'Myapp'
    ready_done = False

        def ready(self):
            if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN') and Myapp.ready_done==False:
                from scripts.recordgen import RecordGenerator
                Myapp.ready_done=True
                Myapp.record_generator = RecordGenerator()
```

In the app directory I have a /scripts/recordgen.py which spawns a basic independent thread adding new data to the database every 60 seconds.  Something like this:

```
import threading
import time
from Myapp.models import results,rawdata

class RecordGenerator(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while (1):
            time.sleep(60)

            #Query the rawdata here and do some calculations
            #Just filling with dummy data for this example
            dummydata = "dummy data"

            new_record = results()
            new_record.data = dummydata
            new_record.save()
```

If records are only added to the results table in this thread, and only read, updated and deleted through Django views, will this be a thread safe implementation?  The database I'm using is Postgre.

Comment: This could be handled in a cron job, no? What platform are you running this on?

Comment: Its linux based.  My understanding is that a cron job to call the "RecordGenerator" script would work too if the environment is setup in the script to allow access to the Django ORM, but isn't this the same as spawning the thread from the app itself?  Is any extra care needed to ensure thread safety when using Django models to manipulate a db table with "filter" and "save" functionality of a model in an external script?